# 'Foo' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#, namespaces

I'm building a library that's called "Fieldsearch" and I **need** people to invoke it like this:

```
FieldSearch x = new FieldSearch();
```

Problem is, if my solution is called `FieldSearch` and my class library is called `FieldSearch.Lib`, I can't call the actual class `FieldSearch`.

```
'Foo' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'
```

What do you suggest I do for this case, sans calling my actual class something else?

Comment: A .NET coding standard is to not name a type the same as its namespace.

Comment: `FieldSearch.FieldSearch x = new FieldSearch.FieldSearch()` ?

Comment: Change your class name if you can, else use it Fully Qualified name, like `namespace.Type` `FieldSearch.FieldSearch`.

Comment: I'm trying to make things simple for the end developers, and using `FieldSearch.FieldSearch` isn't clean. Any other alternatives? Do you suggest just naming the solution/projects something completely unrelated?

Comment: Use the plural "FieldSearches" for you namespace. Like System.Windows.Forms contains a class called Form.

Comment: @MattHamilton: that sounds like a good compromise. Sounds like a plan.

Comment: @MattHamilton - You have my +1 if you create an answer with that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally the best practice is to use the plural form for namespaces and the singular for classes therein. For example, `System.Windows.Forms` contains a class called `Form`.

So in this example, your namespace could be called `FieldSearches` (or `CompanyName.ProductName.FieldSearches` if you want to use that convention). Now the "FieldSearch" class won't match the namespace.

Comment: Uh, what happens when the plural form of something is the same as the singular? Eg The Plural of Software is still software.